Maven Central Not Recognizing Signature Despite Configuration in Gradle Build File
I'm facing an issue where Maven Central does not recognize the signature for my artifacts, even though I have defined the signing configuration in my Gradle build file. Here are the relevant parts of my build.gradle.kts file:
signing {
    useGpgCmd()
    useInMemoryPgpKeys(signingKey, signingPassword)
}

// Configure the Gradle task graph to determine if publishing to Maven Central.
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    // Check if any tasks of type PublishToMavenRepository are targeting Maven Central.
    val isPublishingToMavenCentral = allTasks
        .filterIsInstance<PublishToMavenRepository>()
        .any { it.repository?.name == mavenCentralRepoName }

    // Set signing as required only if publishing to Maven Central.
    signing.setRequired { isPublishingToMavenCentral }

    // Configure each Sign task to only execute if publishing to Maven Central.
    tasks.withType<Sign>().configureEach {
        // Redefine the variable for Config Cache compatibility.
        val publishingToMavenCentralFlag = isPublishingToMavenCentral
        inputs.property("isPublishingToMavenCentral", publishingToMavenCentralFlag)
    }
}

publishing {
    // Publishing configuration...
}

I have generated the GPG key and uploaded it to the Ubuntu key server using the following command:
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys MY-KEY

When I search for my key on the key server, it outputs the following:
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --search-keys MY-KEY

Output:
sec   rsa3072 2024-08-05 [SC]
      MY-KEY
uid           [ultimate] My name (REDWING) <my-email@example.com>
ssb   rsa3072 2024-08-05 [E]

Despite these configurations and steps, Maven Central reports that the signature is missing for the artifacts.
Steps I've Taken:

Generated a GPG key.
Uploaded the GPG key to the Ubuntu key server.
Configured the Gradle build file to use in-memory PGP keys for signing.
Verified the key exists on the key server.

Questions:

Is there something wrong with my Gradle configuration that could be causing Maven Central to not recognize the signature?
Are there additional steps I need to take to ensure the signature is correctly applied and recognized?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
